# Dynamic property keys used in Cypher Query to manipulate properties (regardless of the property values)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is more of a database management question. I'm not trying to extract content stored in properties, but I am trying to clean up a messy database.

For example, I have multiple obsolete properties that start with "type", for example n.typePerson, n.type_Mangoes, n.typehouse, n.dvdTypes.

```
match (n) 
with keys(n) as key, n 
unwind key as k 
with distinct k, n
WHERE tolower(k) contains "type"
with n, k
return k, n[k]
```

--> works fine

```
REMOVE n[k] return n{.*}
```

--> error message

```
WITH distinct n, collect(k) as list
FOREACH (o IN list | REMOVE n[o])
return n{.*}
```

--> error message

I'm hitting a wall when it comes time to do anything with the property. I can return n[k] fine, but I cannot seem to set or remove n[k] without getting this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, whitespace, node labels, '{', 'e/E', a property map, a relationship pattern, '.' or '(' (line 7, column 9 (offset: 136))
"REMOVE n[o]"
```

Most grateful for pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is one of the use cases for using the APOC library in Neo4j, to circumvent the limitations of Cypher where variables cannot be used : labels, relationship types, property keys.

The [`apoc.create.removeProperties`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.removeProperties/#usage-apoc.create.removeProperties) procedure will help you with that :

```
WITH distinct n, collect(k) as list
CALL apoc.create.removeProperties([n], list)
YIELD node
return node{.*}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up removing them one by one but this is nifty for next time!